# Finding the best db design for design Instagram problem

Tags: database-design, cassandra, instagram

I was reading the post given in link:
https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-the-system-design-interview/m2yDVZnQ8lG.
I am having alot of difficulty in understanding the section Database Schema:

https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-the-system-design-interview/m2yDVZnQ8lG#div-stylecolorblack-background-colore2f4c7-border-radius5px-padding5px6-database-schema

Now, this section recomends to store metadata for photos in a nosql store like cassandra.

The questions are:

- With reference to the line as below, what exactly does it mean by that storing the list in different columns?

> For the ‘UserPhoto’ table, the ‘key’ would be ‘UserID’, and the
> ‘value’ would be the list of ‘PhotoIDs’ the user owns, stored in
> different columns.

- While it recommends, using a nosql store, how exactly will this be useful over a rdbms?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck.Out everything but only what is needed to ask your question in your post. Quote/paraphrase with credit as necessary from elsewhere, make your question self-contained. PS rdbms vs nosql is way too broad & vague to ask & yet nevertheless is a duplicate zillions of times over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... what exactly does it mean by that storing the list in different
> columns?

I assume the table schema would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_photos
  userid text,
  photoid int,
  photopath varchar,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (userid, photoid)
)
```

The `PRIMARY KEY` for the table has the partition key as `userid` and `photoid` as a clustering column. It means that each record (identified by `userid`) in the table will have multiple "rows" of `photoid` (clustering column) since each user can have multiple photos.

Cassandra is referred to as a **wide-column store** because data is stored in "wide columns" meaning columns are repeated one or more times as required. To illustrate using the example above, below is a representation of how a record is stored on disk:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+
| PK       | Column 1  | Column 2  | ... | Column n  |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+
| userid = | photoid = | photoid = | ... | photoid = |
| 'abc123' | 56789012  | 78901234  | ... | 90123456  |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+
```

Each record can have one column, or a hundred columns. It depends on how many photos a user has. It isn't a fixed number of columns like traditional RDBMS tables.

> While it recommends, using a nosql store, how exactly will this be useful over a rdbms?

A lot of use cases for NoSQL databases can't be modelled in the traditional two-dimensional RDBMS tables (columns running along the top, rows running down the page).

Like the above example shows, Cassandra supports both the traditional 2D tables but also multi-dimensional tables.

But more importantly, RDBMS cannot achieve scale in the same way that databases like Cassandra does. You can have hundreds or a thousand nodes in a Cassandra cluster and you can have nodes distributed across the globe. There are lots of features and attributes in NoSQL DBs and Cassandra that cannot be achieved with RDBMS. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks alot, this is exactly what I wanted to know.
Just one more small question, lets say that I want to search for the top 20 column values for photoid (order in descending way). Will the search and result be really fast here?

Comment: Just to add to previous comment, 
What if the photoid is of list type? Will cassandra now store it in a different way? 
Which way will be better for storing photoid such that the query to fetch to 20 rows is quicker?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "top 20". The data type is `int` so if you sort it in descending order, it will be newest first. Because of the way data is stored, there is at most 2 disk seeks but in most cases just 1 so reads are very, VERY fast in Cassandra. Most of the clusters I work on have an SLA of 95% reads below 6-8 milliseconds. Cheers!

Comment: There is no reason to store `photoid` as a CQL collection. It is much faster and scalable to store them as columns. There are various reasons for storing data in CQL collections -- there is no reason to do it for this use case. Cheers!